# Apache2: Supply (modified) Environment variable as RewriteCond parameter

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have an Apache2 `RewriteCond` directive that redirects all URL's to a subdirectory on my site, except for a long string of exceptions.

The rule goes as follows: (the long string has been replaced with `foo|bar|baz`)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(foo|bar|baz) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [QSA,L]
```

The regex matches all paths that do not start with `/foo`, `/bar`, `/baz` and redirects them to `/subdir/path/request`.

For example:

```
/foo/page => /foo/page
/bar/page => /bar/page
...
/not_foo/page => /subdir/not_foo/page
/not_bar/page => /subdir/not_bar/page
...
```

What I want to do is to programmatically get this list of exceptions, to reduce code copying (probably with PHP's `getEnv('VAR')`). I've tried a lot of different possible options, but I just can't get it to work.

My idea is to use a `RewriteRule` with `[E=ENV:values]` but I just can't wrap my mind around how to accomplish this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

How about `file_get_contents('.htaccess');`? You can parse the file from there to get what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for a nice solution than just parsing my `.htaccess` file, but I've entertained that route. I'll keep looking for a nicer solution. Thanks!